# What Are Some Techniques For Fast Classical Guitar Runs?

Tags: technique, fingerstyle-guitar, flamenco

Players like Paco de Lucia shred through scales up and down at incredible speed. Is "Picado" the only way to achieve these fast runs up and down the neck?

I'm looking for ways to go up and down a scale with speed using my fingers. I can play fast with a pick but no idea how to do the same using only my fingers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn hammer-ons and pull-offs, more formally known as slurs.

Comment: Paco de Lucia often plays very fast articulated runs, I imagine it's this that OP is talking about.  After all, hammer ons and pull offs are par for the course with a plectrum too.